# How to stream video content in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, streaming, video-streaming

I have the following code which downloads video content:

```
WebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
using (HttpWebResponse wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wreq.GetResponse())
using (Stream mystream = wresp.GetResponseStream())
{
  using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(mystream))
  {
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(wresp.ContentLength);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    buffer = reader.ReadBytes(length);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
    //Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

But the problem is that the whole file downloads before being played.  How can I make it stream and play as it's still downloading?  Or is this up to the client/receiver application to manage?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're reading the entire file into a single buffer, then sending the entire byte array at once.

You should read into a smaller buffer in a `while` loop.

For example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

while(true) {
    int bytesRead = myStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that's it!   Thank you.  I actually did try something like that, but comparing my non-working code to yours, I noticed that I was misusing Response.Flush().  Thanks again, SLaks.

Answer (score 3):

This is more efficient for you especially if you need to stream a video from a file on your server or even this file is hosted at another server

File On your server:

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(HTTPContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_video.Location)));
```

File on external server:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(wc.DownloadData(new Uri("http://mysite/video.mp4")));
```

Comment: cool- but you still have to implement chunked buffers otherwise the video container will wait till the whole thing is downloaded. killing your browser..

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming)?

Look at sample code [here](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/encoder/thread/16450626-6836-48ce-9bab-f5b834056ecd)

Comment: Link to sample code is dead. That's why answers should contain/copy whatever code they refer to.