# Multiple image handler calls causing IE to hang in pop-up window

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, internet-explorer, ashx

We have an **ashx** image handler which has performed fairly well over the last few years, but we've recently noticed some odd intermittent behaviour in **IE8** and **IE9**. We have a gallery page which calls the image handler multiple times as part of an image's src attribute, this page is opened in a pop up window.

The page works fine when but when the window is opened and closed in quick succession (before all the images on the page have finished loading) it causes the browser to hang and subsequently has to be restarted.

Following is a sample of our image handler code, I have a suspicion that the request to the image isn't 'ending' when the window is closed and the connection between the browser and the server is still running and causing it to crash.

Looking at the logs there are multiple attempts to GET the same image via the handler so it looks like the browser is *retrying* as it thinks it has failed to complete the request.

Are there any changes I could make to the handler (or the client code) to ensure the browser doesn't continue requesting the images after the window is closed or is this a baked-in intricacy of IE? Safari, Firefox and Chrome handle this type of behaviour fine.

Alos note: The page displaying the images has an update panel around the grid - but I don't think this is related.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(completeImageFilePath);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    returnImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
returnImage.Dispose();
if (Response.IsClientConnected)
{
    Response.Flush();
}
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping a using around `returnImage` to "ensure" that .dispose() is called?

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
using (System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(completeImageFilePath))
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        returnImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    }
}
if (Response.IsClientConnected)
{
    Response.Flush();
}
Response.End();
```

Comment: @buUKaneer Good call on the _using_ statement for the return image, I've made that change but the issue still occurs. I'm still digging to see if I can trace any more info. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running fiddler at the same time and looking at the raw request/response data - might shed some light on what's actually happening?

Comment: Using Fiddler to profile the very last request before it hangs is a POST within the popup window, the request matches previous POST requests which complete succesfully. I'm now thinking it's something to do with IE's memory management or the fact that it's just not very good at handling fast multiple requests between window pop ups. Still digging...

Comment: I've been doing some reading around the subject - could you try adding the ContentLength header with the size of the image file in bytes to the response - might help to give IE more of a clue as to when items should finish? No idea really if it will help but its another thing to try?!

Comment: Another thing that might make a difference is chunking the response (Sending 4069 bytes at a time) - might cause IE to deal with it differently and circumvent the problem - see the accepted andswer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687677/how-to-stream-video-content-in-asp-net?rq=1