# IE not loading all images in a page with large no: of images(~ 300+ images)

Tags: asp.net, image

I have a webpage which is trying to render more than 300 images, but IE is not rendering all the images. I have detailed the exact scenario below.

I have a aspx page with a asp:Panel. I'm adding new aspx pages to this panel,

```
Image image = new Image();          
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
url.Append(string.Format("ImageDisplay.aspx?Sample={0}", 1));
image.ImageUrl = url.ToString();

HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.Controls.Add(image);
this.pnlImages.Controls.Add(div);
```

the second aspx page writes the image to the response,

```
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = true;

string fileName = "..\\Sample.jpeg";
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(fileName);
image.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

image.Dispose();
Response.Flush();
```

likewise I'm adding more than 300 images.

IE is not rendering all the images properly, most of the images are getting broken and shows as 'X' sign. While the same page loads perfectly fine in Firefox and Chrome. I'm not able to find the cause of the issue since it only happens in IE. Could someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

May get some help here...

1. [Multiple image handler calls causing IE to hang in pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788597/multiple-image-handler-calls-causing-ie-to-hang-in-pop-up-window?answertab=active#tab-top)
2. [Load images fail when I pick multiple image files in my metro style app](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/44a21905-6976-46de-bcd9-58c2077701e8/load-images-fail-when-i-pick-multiple-image-files-in-my-metro-style-app?forum=winappswithcsharp)